# periodically HTTP GET request without using "Submit" input

Tags: http, get, request

I want to make an HTML page that periodically (for example every 0.5 seconds) send an HTTP request to a server using the GET method and without using the "Submit" input of the "form" tag. It's possible to do it? How can I do?

Comment: use javascript http request.

Comment: Thanks. Have you a simple example to give me?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setTimeout()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp), [`setInterval()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) and [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
var getRequest = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/some_url',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
            // some data
        },
        success: function (data) {
            setTimeout(getRequest, 500);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this *shtml* code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Transmit-Receive Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function request_transmit()
        {
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('GET', "http://172.23.159.1/input.cgi?input=on&submit=Submit", true);
          xhr.send();
        }
      function my_timer()
        {
          setInterval(request_transmit, 500);
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="my_timer();">
    <p>
      Received string:  <!--#input-->
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The request is correctly sent to the server but I can't to show the answer in the *shtml* page. The answer is handled by the following block:

```
<p>
  Received string:  <!--#input-->
</p>
```

where "#input" is an SSI command. 
Another problem is the frequency of the HTTP request. If it is greater than 500 milliseconds there are no problems, otherwise, the server goes in time error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Transmit-Receive Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var getRequest = function() {
      $.ajax({
          url: 'http://172.23.159.1/input.cgi?',
          method: 'GET',
          data: {input=on&submit=Submit},
          success: function(data){setTimeout(getRequest, 500);}
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="function();">
    <p>
      Received string:  <!--#input-->
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The HTTP request is correctly sent and received but is not cyclically.